# Link Aggregation Issues (LACP)

Tags: networking, server, 20.04, ping, nic

I am running a nextcloud server on Ubuntu 20.04, and set up link aggregation. It doesn't seem to be working unless the server is in use. For example, if I am running a speedtest on the server, I am able to ping the server locally, but when I close the web browser on the server I can't ping the server even locally, or sometimes it is intermittent. The other issue is when connecting to the server via SSH, it either doesn't work at all, or works with a lot of lag.

Here is my /etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto enp1s0
iface enp1s0 inet manual
bond-master bond0

auto enp3s0
iface enp3s0 inet manual
bond-master bond0

auto bond0
iface bond0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.155
    gateway 192.168.1.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    dns-nameservers 1.1.1.1 1.0.0.1
    slaves enp1s0 enp3s0
    lacp-rate fast
    bond-mode 4
    bond-miimon 100
    bond-slaves none
```

Here is cat /proc/net/bonding/bond0

```
Bonding Mode: IEEE 802.3ad Dynamic link aggregation

Transmit Hash Policy: layer2 (0)

MII Status: up

MII Polling Interval (ms): 100

Up Delay (ms): 0

Down Delay (ms): 0

Peer Notification Delay (ms): 0

802.3ad info

LACP rate: slow

Min links: 0

Aggregator selection policy (ad_select): stable

Slave Interface: enp3s0

MII Status: up

Speed: 1000 Mbps

Duplex: full

Link Failure Count: 0

Permanent HW addr: <mac address here>

Slave queue ID: 0

Aggregator ID: 1

Actor Churn State: churned

Partner Churn State: churned

Actor Churned Count: 1

Partner Churned Count: 1

Slave Interface: enp1s0

MII Status: up

Speed: 1000 Mbps

Duplex: full

Link Failure Count: 0

Permanent HW addr: <mac address here>

Slave queue ID: 0

Aggregator ID: 2

Actor Churn State: none

Partner Churn State: churned

Actor Churned Count: 0

Partner Churned Count: 1
```

I appreciate any insight or leads on what could be causing this behavior. Thank you!